# Mostrar Array y Matriz

Tags: c#

No estoy pudiendo mostrar el array correspondiente a la matriz, solo listo el total de apuestas, pero no veo a quien corresponde:

Tengo este metodo:

```
static void mostrar(int[,] matriz) //MOSTRAR APUESTAS
    {
        for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matriz.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write(matriz[fila, col] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

y aqui lo invoco:

```
case 5://VER TODAS LAS APUESTAS
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t5 - Ver listado de apuestas: ");


                    mostrar(matriz);

                    break;
```

Este es el resto del codigo para entender mejor lo que hace el programa, en el case 1 carga los datos:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] nombre;
        string[] apellido;
        int opcion, tope = 0, cantidad;
        bool seguir = true;





        Console.WriteLine("\t\t*****Bienvenidos al 5 de Oro*****");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de apostantes: ");

        cantidad= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
        nombre = new string[cantidad];
        apellido = new string[cantidad];
        int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];


        while (seguir)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t1-Agregar apuesta");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t2-Agregar apuesta sorpresa");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t3-Eliminar Apuesta");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    4-Ver numeros Cliente");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    5-Ver listado de apuestas");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    6-Ver numeros sin aciertos");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t7-Salir");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Ingrese opcion: ");
            opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcion)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t1 - Agregue una apuesta: ");
                    if (tope < nombre.Length)
                    {

                        Console.Write("Ingrese Nombre: ");
                        nombre[tope] = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                        Console.Write("Ingrese Apellido: ");
                        apellido[tope] = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                        Console.Write("Ingrese su Jugada : ");

                        cargarjugada(matriz, tope);
                        agregar(vector, cantidad, ref tope);








                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No hay mas cupos");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }



                    break;
```

Comment: de donde es el curso que estas haciendo? no sos el primero que pregunta cosas similares sobre este curso, y hay varias preguntas abiertas con el mismo codigo.

Comment: y el vector mostrar solo tiene cantidades, nunca estas pasando el vector que tiene los nombres de los apostadores

Comment: pero cuando le paso el vector de nombres me tira error

Comment: Que es me tira error? Como se lo pasas? Agregaste el parametro?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(nombre[i] + apellido[i]);
                            mostrar(matriz);
                            
                        }`  Me muestra el total de apuestas, pero solo el nombre del primer cliente, los demas no

Comment: Te muestra el nombre de un cliente seguido de todas las apuestas. Creo q justamente es lo q tienea que solucionas voa solo.;) me decis donde es este curso q le genera dudas a tantas personas?

Comment: Somos un equipo y es un instituto privado de Argentina

Comment: Si me podes guiar porque no puedo darme cuenta te agradezco, creo que ya bastante código hice como para querer que me lo resuelvan, no me puedo dar cuenta

Comment: Hay q modificar la funcion mostrar. Mañana si puedo te ayudo. Si no alguien lo hara  debe recibir 2 parametros, los dos vectores a mostrar

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi

Comment: Sería buena idea que hables con https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/49275/francop él también anda desarrollando algo similar. Saludos y bienvenido a SOes :D

Comment: ese user no es el unico @fredyfx.. hay por lo menos 3 mas haciendo lo mismo..

Comment: Si los ubicas, comenta sus perfiles para que se conozcan, ¡La unión hace la fuerza! :D

Comment: gracias por el dato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu funcion mostrar, solo muestra las apuestas, porque en ningun momento esta recibiendo el vector de apostadores-

Dices que te tiro un error al pasarlo, pero no has descripto ni que error ni como trataste de pasarlo.

Sin meterme en si lo que estas haciendo es correcto o no, deberias definir la funcion mostrar como:

```
static void mostrar(int[,] matriz, string[] apellidos)
{
    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
    {
        //para cada fila, mostrar el apellido del apostador
        Console.Writeln(apellidos[fila]);
        for (int col = 0; col < matriz.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            Console.Write(matriz[fila, col] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

y llamarla de la siguiente manera:

```
mostrar(matriz,apellido);
```

Comment: gracias, solamente que en apellidos[i] sustitui la i por fila porque me la marcaba con error, ahora edito tu respuesta para ver si el mostrar un cliente en particular es asi, muchas gracias desde ya

Comment: ok con el cambio de i por fila, no estuve atento ahi. Tu edicion agrega otra consulta a una respuesta y no es correcto. o agregas esa consulta a la pregunta original, o levantas otra pregunta.

Comment: ahi lo modifique

Comment: no, no modifiques la pregunta original porque entonces la respuesta que puse es invalida. Si es un nuevo problema, has una nueva pregunta. Si es un pequeño agregado podemos solucionarlo en los comentarios.

Comment: ok ya formule otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82205/mostrar-posicion-array-en-matriz  gracias