# Posición de un valor en un array

Tags: c#

estoy usando este método:

```
 static void cliente(int[,] matriz, string[] nombre)
        {
            string nom;


            Console.WriteLine(nombre cliente);
            nom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();

            for (int i = 0; i < nombre.Length; i++)
            {
                if (nom == nombre[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nombre[i]);
                }
                for (int col = 0; col < matriz.GetLength(1); col++)
                {

                    Console.Write(matriz[i, col] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

El tema es que a la hora de listar el nombre del cliente y su apuesta, me lista el nombre de ese cliente pero el total de apuestas de todos los clientes.

Comment: Si alejandro el ultimo for tiene que estar adentro del if!

Answer (score 5):

Es que esta funcion hace exactamente lo que decis. Mira la logica de tu funcion. No estas pensando la funcion como lo que tiene que hacer.

```
    static void cliente(int[,] matriz, string[] nombre)
    {
        string nom;


        Console.WriteLine("nombre cliente");
        nom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
        for (int i = 0; i < nombre.Length; i++)
        {
            //comparas el nombre del cliente.. ok es un metodo, 
            //no se si el mejor pero funciona
            if (nom == nombre[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nombre[i]);
            }
            //aca recorres el total de apuestas.. pero no sabes si el cliente era el que querias.. 
            //no deberia estar adentro del if esto?
            for (int col = 0; col < matriz.GetLength(1); col++)
            {

                Console.Write(matriz[i, col] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: gracias @gbianchi, supongo que esos usuarios son parte de la clase, no sabia que habia mas gente en la misma, gracias por la ayuda por el momento

Comment: de nada! es mucha casualidad que todos pregunten al mismo tiempo por el mismo ejercicio.. yo cuestionaria mucho la forma en que les estan enseñando, mas alla de sus dudas (validas) sobre codigo, falta que les expliquen algoritmos basicos (que es donde estan fallando). a varios de aca nos gustaria saber quien les enseña para intercambiar varias palabras con ellos  ;) @eleaefe